# Explicitly find a set of $n$ rationally independent numbers?

Tags: number-theory

We say that a set of real numbers $\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_n$ are *rationally independent* if for rational numbers $y_i$ the only solution of the equation

$$y_1\omega_1+y_2\omega_2+\ldots +y_n\omega_n=0$$
is $y_1=y_2=\ldots=y_n=0.$

For an arbitrary $n$, is there an explicit example of a set of $n$ rationally independent numbers?

Comment: the square roots of the first $n$ primes?

Comment: $\ \left\{\pi^{i-1}\right\}_{i=1}^n \ $